# How to fix this endlessly scrolling ticker?

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations

I need n columns to display endlessly repeating content (see attached gif).

My approach is to clone and append each column's items and then animate `transform: translateY()` for the column height.

This works when I set the height of each item with css (see METHOD 1 in the snippet).

However, when the item height is determined by its content (METHOD 2), the animation skips when looping.

I spent two days but cannot come up with a fix. Does anyone have an idea?

[image]

```js
$(() => {
        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { // 3 columns
          var html = '<div class="column">';
          for(var j=0; j<3; j++) { // 3 items

            // METHOD 1: SETTING RANDOM HEIGHT VIA CSS
            html += '<div class="item" style="height:' + (50 + Math.random() * 100) + 'px"></div>';

            // METHOD 2: SETTING RANDOM HEIGHT VIA CONTENT
            //html += '<div class="item">' + ('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo similique ducimus tempore molestiae ad, maxime obcaecati animi voluptatum ab, neque sed perferendis eveniet est eligendi, officiis dolor aut saepe iste.').substr(0, Math.random() * 1000) + '</div>';

          }
          html += '</div>';
          var $column = $(html).appendTo($('section#ticker-wrapper'));
          var height = $column.height() - parseInt(window.getComputedStyle($column.find(':first-child')[0]).marginTop); // Get height minus one child margin (because of collapsing margins)
          $column.children().clone().appendTo($column);
          $column[0].style.setProperty('--height', -height + 'px');
          $column.css('animation', 'ticker ' + (height / 50) + 's linear infinite');
        }
      });
```

```css
section#ticker-wrapper {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
div.column {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
div.item {
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}
@keyframes ticker { to { transform: translateY(var(--height)); } }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="ticker-wrapper"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I actually found the solution.

The problem was I was determining the height of column 1 before adding the other columns. Because of `flex: 1` adding more columns would sometimes make an item and thus the whole column taller.

The solution was to split the loop into two loops. One to add the items followed by another to determine the heights:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var html = '<div class="column">';
  for(var j=0; j<3; j++) {
    html += '<div class="item">' + ('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo similique ducimus tempore molestiae ad, maxime obcaecati animi voluptatum ab, neque sed perferendis eveniet est eligendi, officiis dolor aut saepe iste.').substr(0, Math.random() * 1000) + '</div>';
  }
  html += '</div>';
  $(html).appendTo($('section#ticker-wrapper'));
}
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var $column = $($('section#ticker-wrapper div.column')[i]);
  var height = $column.height() - parseInt(window.getComputedStyle($column.find(':first-child')[0]).marginTop); // Get height minus one child margin (because of collapsing margins)
  $column.children().clone().appendTo($column);
  $column[0].style.setProperty('--height', -height + 'px');
  $column.css('animation', 'ticker ' + (height / 50) + 's linear infinite');
}
```